# Free Video/Image Editor

Tags: windows, video-editing, audio-editing

I am looking for a software package/suite that can handle editing (cropping, straightening, merging etc.) images and videos. Requirements for the software are as follows:

- Must be freeware, as needs to be installed for the use within an organization;
- Must run on Windows 7 (32, 64 Bit), Windows 8 (32, 64 Bit) and Windows 10 (32,64bit)
- Must support: JPG, JPEG, BitMap, TIF, PNG, and GIF (for images), MKV, AVI and MP4 for videos (handy if any other file types are included)

Additional features that would be nice to include would be:

- Categorizing/Tagging images, and maintaining them within a "library" structure within the application
- Date and Time tagging on the image
- Version Controls
- Watermarks and text

My current solution was Format Factory, but apparently, this does not fit the bill for what we need.

I would greatly appreciate your input as to what other options are out there (..not sure if GIMP would meet my requirements)

Comment: Do you need the *same* software for editing images and videos?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul It does not necessarily need to be the same application/software. It would be _preferable_ but not _required_ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While limited in editing videos, [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) is the premier freeware photo editing tool.  I've used it for years and it's fantastic and open, meaning developers can add tools to extend its usability.  There's also a large number of tutorials available, both from GIMP and from users.